# My amazon interstitial ads don't work....Im calling a function to display them but they dont show up....WHY?

Tags: xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, interstitial, amazon-advertising-api

This is my first time adding Amazon Interstitial Ads and when I try to load up the ads I get this error in my console and the ads don't load.  This is the error that displays in the console and below that is the code. Thank you!

```
2016-01-26 00:09:08.362 RacingGame[8095:2664641] -canOpenURL: failed for   
URL: "about:blank" - error: "(null)"
2016-01-26 00:09:08.499 RacingGame[8095:2664641] -canOpenURL: failed for 
URL: "ios-log:%20preloading" - error: "(null)"
2016-01-26 00:09:08.503 RacingGame[8095:2664641] -canOpenURL: failed for 
URL: "ios-log:%20in%20update%20viewport" - error: "(null)"
2016-01-26 00:09:08.506 RacingGame[8095:2664641] -canOpenURL: failed for 
URL: "ios-log:%20adding%20ios%20viewport" - error: "(null)"
Ad loaded

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
loadAd()
}


func loadAd() {

let interstitialAd = AmazonAdInterstitial()
let adOptions = AmazonAdOptions()

adOptions.isTestRequest = true
interstitialAd.load(adOptions)
interstitialAd.delegate = self
}




//MARK:AmazonAdInterstitialDelegate
func interstitialDidLoad(interstitial: AmazonAdInterstitial!) {
    print("Ad loaded")
}
func interstitialDidFailToLoad(interstitial: AmazonAdInterstitial!, withError error: AmazonAdError!) {

    print("Interstitial failed to load with error \(error.description)")
}

func interstitialDidPresent(interstitial: AmazonAdInterstitial!) {
    print("Interstitial presented")
}
func interstitialWillDismiss(interstitial: AmazonAdInterstitial!) {
    print("Interstitial will dismiss")
}
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665446/canopenurl-problems-adding-site-to-whitelist

Answer (score 0):

also i guess [this](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/18354/unity-ios-plugin-errors-in-the-console-when-loadin.html) will help, These error/warning messages are shown due to security change feature in iOS9. They are generated when your app queries about schemes, e.g. ios-log. You can prevent these warning messages by adding the following entries in your app's plist files: LSApplicationQueriesSchemes ios-log about tel sms