# canOpenURL, problems adding site to whitelist

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I am currently updating an app and using Xcode 7.3.  The app utilizes iAd banner ads and Flurry interstitial ads.  When the iAd banner goes to load I get the error.

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "about:blank" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme about"
```

The banner loads just fine, and everything works as planned.

In researching this I found the method was deprecated for privacy reasons.  However, I can not even find it in any of my files.  Also, I have read about adding sites to a whitelist with LSApplicaitonQueriesSchemes.  I did this in my plist with the following strings in the array;

```
about:blank
about
blank
```

The error then reads;

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "about:blank" - error: "(null)"
```

I can't seem to get rid of the error no matter what I do.  Does anyone have any ideas of what to do?  I see a lot of info for urls that go to social media apps and such, but not for the about:blank url.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You only need to whitelist `about` since that is the scheme being accessed.
2. The message `-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "about:blank" - error: "(null)"` means you have everything working. iOS logs that informational message when an app tries to call `canOpenURL:` for a whitelisted scheme but there is no app installed that supports the given scheme. It's a confusing debug message from iOS that can be safely ignored.